# How to run Python mapreduce in Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to run a mapreduce program in Apache Hadoop that counts an average sum of primes in a given input file.
This is my Mapper

```
import sys
for word in sys.stdin:
   print(word)
```

And this is the Reducer

```
import sys
primes = []
for word in sys.stdin:
    if(int(word) >= 2):
        isPrime = True
        for a in range(2,int(word)):
            if(int(word) % a == 0):
                isPrime=False
        if isPrime:
            primes.append(int(word))
print(sum(primes)/float(len(primes)))
```

Now, when I run it with a following command:

```
python primesMapper.py primesReducer.py -r hadoop --hadoop-streaming-jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.10.0-1.cdh5.10.0.p0.41/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.10.0.jar hdfs://bigdata1.sis.uta.fi:/user/students/input/primes1.txt --output-dir group25/primes.txt
```

I get no error, but nothing actually happens. It just gets stuck on the command. When I manually terminate it I can see it's stuck in the Mapper file:

```
  File "primesMapper.py", line 8, in <module>
    for line in sys.stdin:
```

Any help?

Comment: I've never seen this syntax before. `-r hadoop --hadoop-streaming-jar`

Comment: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run it using

```
hadoop jar <streaming jar_path> -file *mapper_path* -mapper "python primes_mapper.py" -file *reducer_path* -reducer "python primes_reducer.py" -input *input_path* -output *output_path*
```